# Mysql performance selecting blog post views by date

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance

Question about SQL performance when selecting a 'blog post' based on user views by date.

I want to record the user views of each post, and i ll select everyone of them using 'daily' and 'monthly' as parameters:

PS:

Most viewed posts of the day, or month.

To record the views, i created a table to insert, after every page load, the date of each view.

And them select them (count them) by DAY() and MONTH() when needed.

The problem here is, when the table or the amount of users requiring this information grows the select starts to be slower, due to the amount of rows(views) multiplied for the amount of posts.

One alternative that i thought was, create a table for daily records, and another table for monthly records, then on every page load the code checks if there is a row for the selected date, if the rows exist the script increment the views count on it, if it doesn't, the script insert the row with views count = 1;

Ps:

Daily Views
Post ID | Views | Date

1 | 898 | 2014-07-11

2 | 676 | 2014-07-11

1 | 333 | 2014-07-10

This way every post can have only one row per day.

Is there any better option? what do you think about my alternative? there is no need for my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is:

1. Create a table with statistical data with fields:

   - id
   - date (store date  m-d-y)
   - day
   - month
   - year
   - views  (store number of visits)
   - page  (store blog post)

   One unique row per day, and update programmatically as needed.
2. Then you can make queries using `day`, `month`, `year` fields, even you can add weeknum field to make queries to obtain statistics grouped by weeks.
3. As addition you can add a second table to store the full date (m-d-y h:m:s) for each visit, you can add fields like browser, ip, etc... to this table.